# one-to-many mapping for basic type at many side

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to know annotation based one-to-many mapping for basic type for example Person has many nick names. Person is class type and nick name is basic type String. One Person many nick names.

Answer (score 0):

Check out section 2.2.5.3.3 of the [Hibernate Annotations manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-hibspec-singleassoc), which has an example suspiciously similar to yours:

> In some simple situation, do don't
>   need to associate two entities but
>   simply create a collection of basic
>   types or embeddable objects. Use the
>   @ElementCollection  in this case.

```
@Entity
public class User {

   [...]
   public String getLastname() { ...}

   @ElementCollection
   @CollectionTable(name="Nicknames", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="user_id"))
   @Column(name="nickname")
   public Set<String> getNicknames() { ... } 

}
```

Note: In older versions of Hibernate Annotations, `@ElementCollection` was called `@CollectionOfElements`.