# Mapping basic many-to-one with annotation

Tags: hibernate

Please show me how to map collection of basic type using annotation for one-to-many?

Comment: possible duplicate of [one-to-many mapping for basic type at many side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262761/one-to-many-mapping-for-basic-type-at-many-side)

Comment: I don't understand how this question differs from your previous one. If it doesn't, please clarify

Answer (score 0):

```
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="order_id")
//    @Cascade add any cascade options you want
    public Set<LineItem> getLineItems() {
        return lineItems;
    }
```

Comment: No, the question is about basic types (String, etc), not entities.